# npx create-react-app my-app not working. npm ERR! EEXIST

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npx

I am just running `npx create-react-app my-app`  and getting the following error :

```
Creating a new React app in D:\Other computers\My Laptop\Programming [P]\Web Development\Projects\my-portfolio\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path D:\Other computers\My Laptop\Programming [P]\Web Development\Projects\my-portfolio\my-app\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\Other computers\My Laptop\Programming [P]\Web Development\Projects\my-portfolio\my-app\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR! File exists: D:\Other computers\My Laptop\Programming [P]\Web Development\Projects\my-portfolio\my-app\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

I have tried:

- Uninstall and then install Node.js
- Updated npm and npx
- Installed create-react-app globally and then again tried to create app
- tried npm cache clean

Please help !

Comment: Did you try `npx create-react-app my-app --force` as it suggests? Or running it with a name not already used in the current folder

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm cache clean --force`. and I hope it good to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overwrite the contents of `my-app` directory, you can always choose a different name for your react-app. Something like this should work:

`npx create-react-app myapp`

However, if you are not bothered about the already existing directory you can do:

`npx create-react-app my-app --force`

Comment: I don't have a directory already named my-app, so how could I overwrite it ?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Trying removing by running `sudo rm -rf my-app`, maybe fixes the problem?

Comment: I have a doubt. The folder that I am trying to make my react app inside, doesn't exists on my hard disk / ssd . It is on my cloud storage, Gdrive. I access it using a app called backup and sync by Google. Does that have anything to do with it ?